# OpenLayers: parsed GeoJSON points always display at coords(0 , 0)

Tags: vector, coordinates, openlayers, point, geojson

this is the first time i use OpenLayers and i don't understand what i'm doing wrong.

I try to display a simple point parsed from GeoJSON. The data seems to be parsed correctly (i checked with the console) but whatever point i give, it always displays at a position i guess to be LonLat(0,0) on my vector layer.

What am i doing wrong ?

```
var map, baseLayer, placesLayer, geojsonParser ;
// data below have been simplified and reformated to enhance readability
var geojsonData = 
{
    "type":"Feature",
     "geometry":
     {
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[-4.0280599594116,5.3411102294922]
     },
     "properties":
     {
        "id":273,
        "name":"ABIDJAN"
     }
};

$(document).ready(function(){

map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
  baseLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
  placesLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector();

  geojsonParser = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();
  placesLayer.addFeatures(geojsonParser.read(geojsonData));

  map.addLayers([baseLayer,placesLayer]);
  map.setCenter(
    new OpenLayers.LonLat(-4, 5.3).transform(
      new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
      map.getProjectionObject()
    ), 5
  );

}); // document ready
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the right solution:

```
var geojson_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({
                'internalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
                'externalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
            });
```

source: https://gist.github.com/1118357

Comment: @m_x If you found a solution, feel free to add an answer yourself rather than adding it to the question.

Comment: @HaskellElephant yes, this was an old question, i was just starting using SO.

Answer (score 3):

Hi it sounds like you need to transform the long/lat coordinaites into the correct display coordinates:

You can either declare the projections and then transform your geometry feature:

```
var projWGS84 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
var proj900913 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");

feature.geometry.transform(projWGS84, proj900913);
```

Or get the map projection "on the fly" more like this:

```
var projWGS84 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");    
feature.geometry.transform(projWGS84, map.getProjectionObject());
```

Obviously if you are using a different input projection from me change "ESPG:4326" to whatever you require.

HTH

C

EDIT:

In your case you would need to write something like:

```
geojsonData.geometry.transform(projWGS84, map.getProjectionObject());
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i didn't thought about projection matters. I tried to reproject the data in some different ways (parser options, direct processing of parsed data as you suggest) but it does not seem to solve the problem. All that comes to my mind is : WTF ?

Comment: perhaps try var projGoogle = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857");

Comment: Woooooops, my bad, i was fetching the map projection, not the base layer projection (OSM uses 'EPSG:900913'). Now it works !. Thanks for the highlight, and for your time.